# Get the Name of the Workflow from within Custom Activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am trying to create a custom activity for windows workflow that needs to get the name of the workflow file that uses it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to write a tracking participant and add it to the workflows' extensions collection. Your tracker would simply remember the name of the initial activity that launches.

Then your custom activity can query the activity context for an instance of your tracker, and read the "initial" activity executed from it.

I'll give a code example when I'm back in my laptop later today.